# Why does online Java IDE solution throws "error: <identifier> expected"?

Tags: java

I was solving this problem at leetcode.com

I'm not at all looking for solution. I couldn't figure out, why am I getting this error despite checking other answers here.

Problem:
Given a binary tree, find the length of the longest path where each node in the path has the same value. This path may or may not pass through the root.

Note: The length of path between two nodes is represented by the number of edges between them.

Example 1:

Input:

```
          5
         / \
        4   5
       / \   \
      1   1   5
```

Output:

```
2
```

Following is my code that throws

```
Line 25: error: <identifier> expected
```

at `public int longestUnivaluePathHelper(TreeNode root, int long, int prevLongest, int totalHeight)`

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
// rule 1: the univalue can be either left side or right side
// rule 2: it need not go thru root
// rule 3: height < 1000
/*

        1
     2     3

*/

class Solution {
    public int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode root) {
        return longestUnivaluePathHelper(root,1,1,1);
    }

    public int longestUnivaluePathHelper(TreeNode root, int long, int prevLongest, int totalHeight){
        if(totalHeight >= 1000){
            return prevLongest;
        }
        if(root.left == null || root.right == null){
            return prevLongest;
        }else{
            if(root.val == root.left ){
                long++;                
            }else if(root.val == root.right){
                long++;
            }else{
                prevLongest = long;
                long = 1;
                totalHeight++;
            }
            longestUnivaluePathHelper(root.left, long, prevLongest, totalHeight);
            longestUnivaluePathHelper(root.right, long, prevLongest, totalHeight);
        }
        //return prevLongest;
    }
}
```

Comment: `long` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a variable name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is a key word in java,you should not use it as parameter name

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `long` for any identifier name since it's a reserved keyword. Rename the method parameter e.g.

```
public int longestUnivaluePathHelper(TreeNode root, int value, int prevLongest, int totalHeight)
```

Take a look at [Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) to see which keywords are reserved.